# Simple LINQ Select Statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having basic difficulties with LINQ select statement.

What I want is quite simple : I have an ID. I use that ID to get certain value from the table. It does work, but with a twist...

Here is the code:

```
var myDate = dbContext.tbl_mytable.Where(i => i.myID == item.myID)
                          .Select(i => new {Name = i.KeySourceDate});
```

I was expecting a `DateTime` in myDate. Image shows what I got instead.

[image]

I understand the final value of name = thedate, since it's in the select statement.

What I need at the end is JUST a date formatted like this .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), and not the whole object, or whatever comes from the LINQ.

Comment: `.Select(i => i.KeySourceDate.ToString("YourFormat"));`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were retrieving a list of rows that have an ID, but what you said you wanted was a single datetime.  There are many ways of doing it, depending on what you want to happen in the cases where multiple rows are found with that id, or if no rows are found with that id, but here is one such way:

```
var myDate = dbContext.tbl_mytable.First(i => i.myID == item.myID).KeySourceDate;
```

Comment: It is bad practice to format dates in the data layer, and as such, I've skipped that part since he should be doing it in the UI portion.

Comment: You can also use .Single if you want an error thrown if there is more than 1 row with the specified ID.  You can also do `.Where(i=>i.myID==item.myID).Select(i=>i.KeySourceDate).FirstOrDefault();` if you are unsure if the record even exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate if the `Id` exist before to try to get the result.
But basically, you can get the date using:

```
DateTime? myDate;
var record = dbContext.tbl_mytable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.myID == item.myID);
if (record != null){
myDate = record.KeySourceDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of ocurse you get a DateTime object when you request a date field by Linq. All you have to do, is to call the toString() method with a formatter string as parameter when you assign the value, like: 
  ...

```
new { Name = i.KeySourceDate.toString("dd/MM/yyyy") }
```

Comment: Supposing he's using a LINQ provider backed by a database, there's a strong likelihood that the `ToString()` method won't be supported.